# React Native Flatlist Remove Item Removing Last Item

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

I am using "react-native-swipe-list-view" to try to remove an item.  For some reason when I try to remove an item it is removing the last item from the flatlist even though that item is still showing in the array and the correct item is removed.

Basically always the last item is removed from the flatlist when I remove an item even though that item is still present in the array of data.  Very weird activity.  And when I leave and come back to the page the correct data shows.

CoinList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View , AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import CoinListRow from './CoinListRow';


class CoinList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      coinList: null
    };
  }


  updateCoinList = (updatedCoins) => {
    this.setState(
      {coinList: updatedCoins}
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("coins").then(value => {
      // need to convert returned object into an array
      this.setState({coinList: Object.values(JSON.parse(value))})
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.coinList !== null ? <FlatList
          data={this.state.coinList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          extraData={this.state}
          renderItem={({item}) => <CoinListRow style={styles.item} item={item} updateCoinList={this.updateCoinList}/>}
        /> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default CoinList;
```

CoinListRow:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { ListItem } from "react-native-elements";
import { SwipeRow } from "react-native-swipe-list-view";

import images from "../../assets/logos/coinLogos";

class CoinListRow extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      coinInfo: null,
      disableInterstitialBtn: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    return fetch(`https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets/${item.card.slug}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          coinInfo: responseJson.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  removeCoin = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('coins')
    .then((coins) => {
      AsyncStorage.removeItem('coins');
      let c = coins ? JSON.parse(coins) : {};
      delete c[this.props.item.card.slug]
      AsyncStorage.setItem('coins', JSON.stringify(c));
      this.props.updateCoinList(Object.values(c));
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error);
      alert(error);
    }
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { coinInfo } = this.state;
    const { item } = this.props;
    console.log(this.state.coinInfo);
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.coinInfo ? (
          <SwipeRow disableRightSwipe={true} rightOpenValue={-120}>
            <View style={styles.standaloneRowBack}>
              <Text style={styles.backTextWhite}></Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.removeCoin}><Text style={styles.backTextWhite}>Remove Item</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View>
              <ListItem
                key={item.card.slug}
                leftAvatar={{ source: images[item.card.slug] }}
                title={coinInfo.name}
                titleStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                subtitle={coinInfo.symbol}
                onPress={this._openInterstitial}
                chevron
                bottomDivider={true}
              />
            </View>
          </SwipeRow>
        ) : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(CoinListRow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to run a componentDidUpdate based on the changing props.  I was going to make a snack and then realized I forgot to save my code when I did a git stash:

I was thinking if I updated the props in the parent component that it would then automatically trigger a refresh by passing new props, but since the component is already mounted I needed to do the refresh after the fact.

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { item } = this.props;
    if (prevProps.item !== this.props.item) {
      return fetch(`https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets/${item.card.slug}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          coinInfo: responseJson.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could come from this :

```
removeCoin = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('coins')
    .then((coins) => {
      AsyncStorage.removeItem('coins');
      let c = coins ? JSON.parse(coins) : {};
      delete c[this.props.item.card.slug]
      AsyncStorage.setItem('coins', JSON.stringify(c));
      this.props.updateCoinList(Object.values(c));
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error);
      alert(error);
    }
    )
  }
```

You use an Async function but you don't really wait that it finished before updating your Coin. Not really sure, but you can try by this way (Maybe you will need to edit it) :

```
removeCoin = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('coins')
    .then((coins) => {
      AsyncStorage.removeItem('coins');
      let c = coins ? JSON.parse(coins) : {};
      delete c[this.props.item.card.slug]
      this.setState({coinItem: c});
    }).then(async() => {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('coins', JSON.stringify(this.state.coinItem));
    }).then(() => {
      this.props.updateCoinList(Object.values(this.state.coinItem));
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error);
      alert(error);
    }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it actually is updating and I can see that the state is correct, but it is removing the last row instead of the correct row.  When I navigate out and back in it logs the correct state/ so the coin that is being removed is actually no longer in the list and the last row is now back in with the correct coin.

Comment: Maybe you could reproduce it on a Snack ? Will be more easy to help.